# C++ call stack - execution returning to a deleted object

Tags: c++, destructor

Let's say I have something like this in call stack:

main()-->classMethod()-->someFunction()

someFunction() deletes the class, which was allocated with new operator, and returns.
If class has a bool attribute X which is set to true in destructor, is it safe to read it right after someFuntion() returns? Like this:

```
SomeClass::~SomeClass() { X = true; }
void SomeClass::classMethod()
{
   someFunction(); // deletes this class object
   if(X) return;
   //something else
}
```

I ran similar code with valgrind and it reported "Invalid read" when accessing X attribute, which is not as surprising.

The thing is, I ran it a lot of times (maybe ~ 30 - 50) and it never crashed or such.
Did I just get very lucky and should avoid doing that?

Comment: You just got *unlucky*. Accessing things in a deleted object is Undefined Behavior. But it's safe to return up the call chain from a method that does an object hara-kiri, as long as you don't access things in the object.

Answer (score 1):

To access any member variables of an object after it has been deleted is cause for undefined behavior. No, it is not safe to access `X` member after the object has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The result of reading any value from a deleted instance is undefined. It probably won't crash but it can read garbage (data of another instance that was allocated at the same place).

Btw. you can do the very same thing safely with exceptions.